# How to walkthrough tree and accumulate multiply the value of path

Tags: kdb, k

There is a tree:

- Each row is a path `parent node --> child node`
- `data` means the value of this path.

```
tree:([]parent:`A`A`A`B`B`E`E;child:`B`C`D`E`F`G`H;data:(1;2;3;4;5;6;7));
```

My question is:

- For every **non-leaf** node (Red node in the chart), we can get a subtree based on this non-leaf node as root.
- Then we can get paths: `root -> every leaf node`
- plus, we can get a value to every path, `value = multiply each data on this path`

This chart shows what I want to say.

---

For myself, I can get every paths like this.
But, I was stuck on how to calculate the data when walkthrough the tree.

```
map: exec child by parent from tree;
pl:exec distinct parent from tree; / parent list
(map\)pl / get all paths from every non-leaf node
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see the image due to workplace restrictions......is the image hosted externally or embedded? Maybe try embedding it if possible?

Comment: The image url is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofNyJ.png

Comment: Hmmm, still not embedded. I think imgur is the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
q)show paths:(distinct tree`parent),'1; /init paths
`A 1
`B 1
`E 1
q)show paths:{raze{wp:flip value exec child,data from tree where parent in x 0;$[count wp;wp,\:;enlist]x}each x}/[paths]; /build paths
(`G;6;`E;4;`B;1;`A;1)
(`H;7;`E;4;`B;1;`A;1)
(`F;5;`B;1;`A;1)
(`C;2;`A;1)
(`D;3;`A;1)
(`G;6;`E;4;`B;1)
(`H;7;`E;4;`B;1)
(`F;5;`B;1)
(`G;6;`E;1)
(`H;7;`E;1)
q)paths:{reverse 2 cut x}each paths;
q)show res:raze{(x[0;0],'(1_x)[;0])!1_prds x[;1]}each paths; / results include waypoints as well
A B| 1
A E| 4
A G| 24
A H| 28
A F| 5
A C| 2
A D| 3
B E| 4
B G| 24
B H| 28
B F| 5
E G| 6
E H| 7
q)waypoints:(!/)tree`parent`child;
q)end:end where not(end:value waypoints)in key waypoints;
q)show res:(k where(k:key res)[;1]in end)#res; / to get only child from parent
A G| 24
A H| 28
A F| 5
A C| 2
A D| 3
B G| 24
B H| 28
B F| 5
E G| 6
E H| 7
```

The solution provided is not optimized but provides a general idea on how such a problem should be approached.

- Keeping a list of paths while iterating through all possible paths and keeping a score
- To improve the solution, you can do the product within the loop and just keep the start and end position with the final score, instead of storing all the waypoints and scores.

Answer (score 0):

Steps through the tree from leaves to roots and maintains the running product at each step.

```
tree:([]parent:`A`A`A`B`B`E`E;child:`B`C`D`E`F`G`H;data:1 2 3 4 5 6 7);

sort:{x iasc 2#/:x:x@'(-1+count each x),\:1 0}
step:{.[z;(::;0);*;]y -2#/:z:(z,'x l)where(l:last each z)in key x}

walk:{
    d:exec child!parent from x;
    w:exec(child,'parent)!data from x;
    sort raze 1_(step[d;w;]\)1,'(except/)x`child`parent
    }

walk tree
`A `C 2
`A `D 3
`A `F 5
`A `G 24
`A `H 28
`B `F 5
`B `G 24
`B `H 28
`E `G 6
`E `H 7
```